# JavaScript: space keydown sometimes not detected with multiple keypresses

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, events, addeventlistener

While working on a little gameengine, I noticed that sometimes space keydown event isn't triggered in some cases.

- When keeping left arrow key down, and pressing space, it works
- When keeping left and up arrow keys down, then pressing space, it doesn't work

The weird thing is that when doing the same test with right and up arrows down, and pressing space, it works.

Same thing happens with Chrome & Firefox on Windows. It seems it works as expected in MacOSX.

See: http://jsbin.com/takiyekudu/1/

Anyone knows why it doesn't work and has an idea how to workaround this bug ?

Comment: It's probably not your webpage - it's more likely a hardware issue: [Keyboard Ghosting](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx)

Comment: Oh, so it's a hardware problem. I guess there is no workaround then  ?

Comment: Probably not.  On my system, I see the same issue, but also note that it registers the space key when I hold left & right, left, down & right, down & right and up & right - so looks like both our keyboards are wired in a way that left, up and space conflict.